# Write results in matrix: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: matrix, igraph, vertex

I am new to igraph and wanted to ask about this error popping up when I try to save my results in a matrix. The first row is supposed to be the vertex names. Anyone got an idea what might cause this?

> vcount(Net1997)
>   [1] 188
>
> Results1997<-matrix(0,nrow=188,ncol=11)
>
> Results1997[,1]<-get.vertex.attribute(Net1997,"vertex.names")
>   Error in Results1997[, 1] <- get.vertex.attribute(Net1997, "vertex.names") : 
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Solved the problem, apparently used the wrong command for names in igraph                                                                                   v<-c(V(Net1997)$name)
Results1997<-matrix(0,nrow=188,ncol=12)
Results1997[,1]<-v